# Is there any way to get a parentNode from an Object?

Tags: javascript, object

Suppose I access a certain object that is inside an object, but I don't know what the key of the previous object is, is there any way to get the key of the parent of this object?

`Basically I would like to get the relative node of a property of an object`

```
var house = {
  bedroom: {
    bed: 'I am a bed'
  }
}
```

I got `I'm a bed`, I know her key is `bed` but I don't know she is in `bedroom` is there any way to get `bedroom?` just by knowing `bed`. It is similar to parentNode, but like in objects.

**This is my wish**: "`bed.parentNode`result `bedroom`" but in object;

Comment: you have to set a property on bedroom to reference its parent node

Comment: @about14sheep I don't understand, could it be more specific? Thanks

Comment: I'm curious about this part `I know her key is bed `. Can you give some more detail on how exactly do you know that the key is `bed`?

Comment: I was gonna suggest getting every second object node and Iterate to find the key by its value but that might be an issue if you have multiple bed key words which might be under a different node.

Comment: @MihaiParaschivescu I'm not OP but I think they are just referencing their example

Comment: when you create the object you will need to hold a reference to each parent node in order to look it up with bed.parentNode.

Comment: @MihaiParaschivescu I know I'm in bed, because I have bed, but I don't know which parent `bet` is in, I don't mean I just have `I'm a bed`, but I have the full property, key e value

Comment: @about14sheep I'm not creating this object itself, I'm getting it through ajax

Comment: @about14sheep I basically do a database lookup on a table that's in json, and my return would be the whole house object, but I need to get the parent nodes of the property itself of the house object I'm on

Comment: It's a seemingly simple question, but I'm probably not able to explain it simply. `Basically I would like to get the relative node of a property of an object`

Comment: Think about it: what would happen if you put the same value inside many different objects, what answer should you get out of your hypothetical operation then? TLDR, this is not possible unless you somehow implement the link to whatever it is you consider the parent manually.

Comment: @jon Thanks, I thought about it too, anyway thanks

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this is while you are iterating through the object, store the key as a variable.

```
function recurseObject(obj, parentNode) {
    let result;
    if (typeOf obj !== 'object') {
        return
    }
    for(const key in obj) {
        if(//house[key] is the element you want the parent node of) {
             return parentNode
        }
        result = recurseObj(obj[key], key)
    }
    return result
}
```

This function simply recurses through an object passing it the previous key. When you find the value you want the parent node for you simple return it. If the logic in the `if` block does not find what you want it will return undefined

- This is simply a function to iterate through the object storing the previous key. I think there would be a much cleaner approach to this, however I would need to see more of your logic

Comment: Ok, for today i've reached my limit, but tomorrow, analyzing your answer, i'll give you a grade, thank you

Comment: What happens in there is a bed in both the house['bedroom'] and house['cellar']? I'm asking more for the OP's sake, and not for yours, because I think what you've done is correct.

Comment: then OP will have to get very explicit with his if statement. maybe `if(obj[key] === 'bed' && parentNode !== 'cellar')` I think the best option is try something else entirely. Where you dont need to reverse lookup an objects key.